# Is $D=\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}: \left | x \right |\leq 1 \right \}$ a discrete valuation ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

A [discrete valuation ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring) (DVR) is a principal ideal domain (PID) with exactly one non-zero maximal ideal.

Is $D=\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}: \left | x \right |\leq 1 \right \}$ a discrete valuation ring?

Comment: No, it is not a ring.

Comment: It is not even a ring.

Comment: Love the chance to write this: $1+1 = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ring axiom for closure under addition.

Indeed $1 \in D$ since $1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|1|=1 \leq 1$.

Now consider $1+1$ using $+$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$, $1+1=2\notin D$ since $|2|=2 \nleq 1$ hence $D$ does not satisfy closure under addition and so $D$ is not a ring.

So obviously $D$ cannot be a discrete valuation ring.